# How can I extract a string from between last dash and second to last dash out of a column that contains lists of strings?

Tags: r, regex, string, stringr, gsub

I have some data and I want to make a new column with the string that is between the last dash and the second to last dash. But there is a twist! Some of my observations are "listed", and I want to get each target string out of the list items as well.

Example data here:

```
data <- data.frame(
  a = c("1500925OR3-29139-315012", 
        "1500925OR3-2-2913A-315012", 
        "c(\"1500925OR3-200B-315012\", \"1500925OR3-4-2919999-315012\")")
)
```

looks like:

```
                                                           a
1                                    1500925OR3-29139-315012
2                                  1500925OR3-2-2913A-315012
3 c("1500925OR3-200B-315012", "1500925OR3-4-2919999-315012")
```

I want data that looks like this

```
        a_clean
1         29139
2         2913A
3 200B, 2919999
```

I've been working on using regex, but I can't figure out how to get the string before the last dash. This grabs the stuff after the last dash...`-[^-]*$` but obviously thats not right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this regex in `sub` and use `lapply`.

```
dat$b <- lapply(dat$a, \(x) sub('-?.*-(.*)-.*', '\\1', x, perl=TRUE))
dat
#                                                     a             b
# 1                             1500925OR3-29139-315012         29139
# 2                           1500925OR3-2-2913A-315012         2913A
# 3 1500925OR3-200B-315012, 1500925OR3-4-2919999-315012 200B, 2919999
```

You're talking about a "list" column, so I created one assuming that's what your real data looks like.

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(a = list("1500925OR3-29139-315012", "1500925OR3-2-2913A-315012", 
    c("1500925OR3-200B-315012", "1500925OR3-4-2919999-315012"
    ))), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2):

A `tidyverse` approach:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  separate_rows(a, sep = "\\s") %>% 
  mutate(b = str_extract(a, "(?<=-)[^-]*(?=-[^-]*$)")) %>% 
  summarise(a_clean = toString(b), .by=id) %>% 
  select(-id)
```

```
 a_clean      
  <chr>        
1 29139        
2 2913A        
3 200B, 2919999
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively,

```r
data.frame(
  a = c(
    "1500925OR3-29139-315012",
    "1500925OR3-2-2913A-315012",
    "c(\"1500925OR3-200B-315012\", \"1500925OR3-4-2919999-315012\")"
  ),
  b = c(1:3)
) %>% separate_rows(a, sep = '\\,') %>% separate(a,
                                                 c('col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'),
                                                 sep = '\\-',
                                                 fill = 'left') %>% group_by(b) %>%
  summarise(col3 = str_c(col3, collapse = ","))
```

```r
# A tibble: 3 × 2
      b col3        
  <int> <chr>       
1     1 29139       
2     2 2913A       
3     3 200B,2919999
```